# what is this centipede like creature?

Tags: species-identification

They are very big. About the size of my hand in length and I've seen two now. My cat brought one in from the Texas border region. [image]

Comment: giant centipede. Probably a Common Desert Centipede (Scolopendra polymorpha)

Comment: Yes ,surely a centipede.Looks similar to the ones on https://extensionentomology.tamu.edu/insects/centipede/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dark bands between segments and long tails match:

[image]

Distribution matches:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I’m fairly sure it *is* a centipede. However, the picture is too fuzzy to make out the exact species.

You can try comparing with the many recorded observations of centipedes around Texas: https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=18&taxon_id=49556